# can i use a string as a whole string after cutting it to head and tails (a:as) and using recursion on it in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use every character in the string in a function i have (that uses only one Char) but i am also trying to use that same string as a whole in the same recursive function to compare it to indvidual characters in another string (using `elem`). Is there a way i can use that string heads and tails and also the whole string, so that the string will not be cut after every recursion?

Code:

```
checkTrue :: TrueChar -> Char -> [Char] -> TruthValue
checkTrue a b c
            | a == IsTrue b                             = AbsoluteTrue
            | (a == IsFalse b) && (b `elem` c)          = PartialTrue
            | otherwise                                 = NoneTrue

checkTruths :: [TrueChar] -> [Char] -> [TruthValue]
checkTruths [][] = []
checkTruths (a:as) (b:bs) = checkTrue a b (removeAbsoluteTrue (a:as) (b:bs)): checkTruths as bs 
{-  This is the line, 
i wanted to use b as a string and also as b:bs. is this possible? -}
checkTruths _ _ = [NoneTrue]
```

Comment: use `aAndas@(a:as)` where `aAndas` will refer to the whole of `a:as`

Comment: @user1984 in that case, will ```a``` still refer to the whole string?

Comment: Use `wholeString@(headOfString : tailOfString)` -- here I named the variables with their meaning. You can use all three variables as you'd like. (You can rename these three variables as you want, of course.)

Comment: It's `aAndas` or as chi better named them `wholeString` and it refers to the whole string that is passed to the function as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want an as-pattern, as [documented](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#dx8-59009) in Section 3.17.1 of the Haskell 2010 report.

> Patterns of the form *var@pat* are called *as-patterns*, and allow one to
> use *var* as a name for the value being matched by *pat*. For example,
>
> ```
> case e of { xs@(x:rest) -> if x==0 then rest else xs }
> ```
>
> is equivalent
> to:
>
> ```
> let { xs = e } in
>   case xs of { (x:rest) -> if x==0 then rest else xs }
> ```

In your function, you'd write

```
checkTruths alla@(a:as) allb@(b:bs) = checkTrue a b (removeAbsoluteTrue alla allb): checkTruths as bs
```